# Ordinal $10^\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

$10^\omega$ = $10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot ...= \lim_{\alpha \lt \omega} (10^\alpha) = \omega$. Are my thoughts correct? Is this sufficient explanation, given the ordinal arithemtic proved from ZFC?

Comment: The question whether the explanation is sufficient depends completely on what you want to use the explanation for.

Comment: I want to demonstrate that $10^ω = ω$.

Comment: What I mean is that an explanation suitable for convincing me will likely be different than an explanation that convinces you, which in turn may be different than the explanation needed for homework solutions. But: you **do** have the right calculation; I am just trying to let someone else answer so they can gain some "reputation points" on this site.

Comment: If you're interested, I posted a summary of some ordinal arithmetic results in [this 25 September 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5173122) at Math Forum. I planned to follow this up (as indicated [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5173825)) but after a few months decided the amount of effort needed to post stuff like this in ASCII just wasn't worth it -- I'd be better off writing a LaTeX document (haven't yet done so) that also wouldn't be subject to the whims of those who archive sci.math posts (Math Forum, google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it would be better if you referred to the appropriate definition of ordinal arithmetic.

For an ordinal $\alpha$ and a limit ordinal $\beta$ (like e.g. $\beta = \omega$) exponentiation is defined as

$\alpha^\beta = \bigcup_{\gamma < \beta} \alpha^\gamma$

Replacing the appropriate values in the definition we therefore have:

$10^{\omega} =  \bigcup_{n < \omega} 10^n$

Since for $n \le m$ we have the set inclusion $10^n \subseteq 10^m \subseteq \omega$ it should now become apparent that $\bigcup_{n < \omega} 10^n = \bigcup_{n < \omega} n = \omega$.